# windows 10. File explorer suddenly terribly slow

Tags: performance, windows-explorer

I have a very fast computer. No problem working with it. Until now. 
I decompressed a zip file that contained 5 json files. 
The zip took a lot to decompress, so I cancel it.

Since then, no matter if I restart the computer file explorer is incredibly slow.
If I press (windows key)+E , file explorer does not open (as before)
and to load the icons takes like 5 minutes

Also the green bar in the upper side is slow

Is there something slowing my file explorer? Any help will be welcome

Comment: Have you checked what Task Manager says when trying to open File Explorer?

Comment: what exactly should I look in the Taak manager?

Comment: Well, to see if the process is comming up and if there is an unusual high need of ressources for the process.

Comment: You can also try to clean cache like **CCleaner** or try maybe a `sfc /scannow` (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

Answer (score 2):

Took me days to figure this out - but here is how I went about identifying the root cause.

1. I confirmed that my issue was triggered a few seconds after login into my windows machine. I simply navigated directories upon login and 10-15 seconds later I would experience the issue.
2. To be certain it was a program and not the Windows OS I used `msconfig` and did a `Selective startup` with just `Load system services`. Restarted the computer, logged in and after 5 minutes or so I still had not experiencing the issue.[image: Used MSCONFIG]
3. To narrow down the program I used Windows 10 `Startup Apps` - Disabled all then enabled one by one I enabled (restart on each change) until the found the culprit - [Box Drive](https://www.box.com/resources/downloads/drive). Box Drive may not be the root cause for you but with this process you should be able to narrow down the issue, if its 3rd party software. [image: Startup Apps]
4. Other symptoms aside from a sluggish/unresponsive File Explorer were Unable to Shut Down or Restart properly (had to hold the power button to turn PC off)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is a complete reboot. 
`shutdown /s /f /t 0`
As windows reboot in Newer versions is not same as old versions for the sake of faster boot times.
If your problem persists consider posting a screenshot of task manager here. It is a general issue with Windows which may occur randomly.

Comment: What if we try a complete reboot without that hibernation (which it usually does) [Sorry I do not use Windows anymore]

Comment: That is why I pasted the command for that. Feel free to edit it in. I need it 3-4 times per year after windows get extremely slow and large (8GB+) mapped files keep stuck in memory.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the most common causes for slow explorer performance are:

1. cloud drives (dropbox, google drive, etc. paired with a slow connection or high latency)
2. backup tools
3. anti virus scans
4. malware (quite unlikely though)

In general I'd reccomend to investigate with the "**Resource Monitor**" just search it in the Windows 10 search box.