# File explorer preview incredibly slow Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, preview

I have recently upgraded an engineer on our site to windows 10. Our engineers use the file explorer preview pane extensively on DWG files as this saves them from having to load each file to know what they are looking at. However, Since the upgrade to Windows 10, the preview is so slow, that it's barely faster than opening the whole file. This includes all files such as PDF, MSG, DOCX, etc. I'm confident that this is not a hardware limitation. Hardware is as listed:

- i7 8700k
- 32GB DDR4 RAM
- M.2 SSD 960 Evo Drive
- Quadro P2000 GPU

What would be causing the slow preview, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check CPU and RAM usage? And which process has highest usage? Also check those background tasks and background services.

Comment: No noticeable spikes correlating with the issue

Comment: do you use resilio sync? it might be the issue

Comment: If you use Box Drive see my answer https://superuser.com/a/1539422/332248

Comment: Same problem here, especially in folders containing many pictures. The whole thumbnail-preview system in Windows has some serious performance issues.